# Reasoning behind domain and range of f(x)

Tags: functions

for $ f(x) = \sqrt{\ln|x|}-4$ the domain is $[1, \infty)$ and range is $[-4, \infty)$. Why so? There is no reasoning provided in the textbook answer.

Comment: Do you know that the domain of $\sqrt{x}$ is $x\geq 0$? So you have the equation $\ln(x)\geq 0$. Can you solve it?

Comment: still a bit lost...

Comment: Write both sides of the inequality as an exponent of e: $$e^{\ln(x)}\geq e^0$$ Can you go on?

Comment: @callculus42 What I am confused about is that why is the domain only positive numbers when there is an absolute number bar which will anyway give x's positive value even if x is negative

Comment: OK, if there is really an absolute bar then the equality is $e^{\ln(|x|)}\geq e^0$

Comment: Not only the argument inside the log need be positive but also the expression you get under the square root should also be positive. Do you know that $\ln(x)<0$ if $0<x<1$? . Try and graph the function

Comment: The input for ln must even be positive. $0$ is not allowed either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of $f(x) = \sqrt{\ln|x|}-4$ is $(-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty)$.

The function $f(x) = \sqrt{\ln(x)}-4$, however, does have a domain $[1,\infty)$. Let me explain why.

First lets understand why the domain of $\sqrt{x}$ is $[0,-\infty)$.

To see this, understand how the square root function is defined:

$$\sqrt{9}=3 \iff 3*3=9$$

Now, let's say that $x$ is a negative number and $\sqrt{x}=y$. Then we must have that $y*y=x$. But no matter whether $y$ is negative or positive we will still have that $y*y$ is positive.

We can now see that $\sqrt{x}$ has a domain of $[0,\infty)$

Now, your function is $f(x) = \sqrt{\ln(x)}-4$. We need to make sure that we do not plug in a value of $x$ such that $\ln(x)$ is negative, because we are plugging $\ln(x)$ into the square root function, which we know has domain $[0,\infty)$.

Now, recall how the function $ln(x)$ works:

$$\ln(x)=y \iff e^y=x$$

if $x \leq 0$, then $ln(x)$ is undefined, because $e^y >0$.

Thus $(-\infty,0]$ is not in the domain of $f(x)$.

Now, suppose $0<x<1$. In this case, we have that $e^y<1$ and thus $y<0$. Therefore, when $0<x<1$ we have that $ln(x)<0$.

Thus $(0,1)$ is not in the domain of $f(x)$.

So $(-\infty,0] \cup (0,1)$ is NOT in the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{\ln(x)}-4.$ However, for any number in $[1,\infty)$, we have that $ln(x) > 0$ and thus $f(x)$ will be well defined. The minus four does not effect the domain, since given any number, we can always subtract four.

Thus the domain of $f(x)$ is $[1,\infty)$

To see that the range of this function is $[-4,\infty)$, we first note that this is an INCREASING function. That is to say, if $x_1<x_2$, then $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$. This is clear because $\sqrt{x}$ and $\ln(x)$ are both increasing functions. In particular, this means that the smallest number in the domain will produce the smallest number in the range. Thus the smallest number in the range of $f(x)$ is:

$$f(1)=\sqrt{ln(1)}-4 = \sqrt{0}-4 = -4$$

To see that the range has no upper bound, we note that both $\ln(x)$ and $\sqrt{x}$ have no upper bound. That is to say, given any value $y>0$, there exists a value $x_0$ such that $\ln(x_0)>y$ and $\sqrt{x_0}>y$.

Thus the range of $f(x)$ is $[-4,\infty)$.

The fact that the domain of $\sqrt{\ln|x|}-4$ is $(-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty)$ follows identical arguements as the case illustrated, combined with the fact that if $x$ is negative then $|x|=-x$.

Comment: Please carefully review [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2|134.8271).  It applies all users, even users that are Frogs.  Consider yourself notified.

Comment: So are you trying to say that the domain of f(x) is [1,∞) or is it (-∞,-1]u[1,∞)

Comment: If you have the absolute value symbol on the $x$, the domain is $(-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty)$. If the absolute value symbol is not there, the domain is just $[1,\infty)$